# Handling Option[A] where function takes A as a parameter

Tags: scala

I have a case class `Foo` which has a field `baz: Option[List[Bar]]`.

Also, I have a function - `def f(baz: List[Bar])`

I need to pass the `List[Bar]` to `f()`.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option is great because it forces you to come to grips when there is no item. In the case of a `List`, `Option` may be overkill as there already exists a corresponding `empty`, i.e. they are both Monads:

```
f(myOptList getOrElse Nil)
```

wherein I'd say you should probably only have a `List` ever. Otherwise you deal with a trinary case: Something that is empty, something that has items and empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
case class Baz(b: Int)
case class Foo(bazs: Option[List[Baz]])

val foo = Foo(Option(List(Baz(1), Baz(2))))
foo.bazs.map(list => f(list))
```

`Option` is a monad, if it's a `Some` the map will we applied to it, else if it's a `None` nothing will happen, from the REPL:

```
scala> def f(b: List[Baz]) = b.foreach(println)
f: (b: List[Baz])Unit

scala>     foo.bazs.map(list => f(list))
Baz(1)
Baz(2)
res1: Option[Unit] = Some(())

scala> val foo = Foo(None)
foo: Foo = Foo(None)

scala>     foo.bazs.map(list => f(list))
res2: Option[Unit] = None
```